# URLScan - Filtering Form Data

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, urlscan

Using URLScan from microsoft, do you know of any way to scan the form data for malicious input? The equivalent of validateRequest (from asp.net) but for classical asp? I want to block all data received from the browser that has potentially malicious input, for example, input that contains < script > elements or other forms of xss

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing built in.  Here's some suggestions:

http://aspalliance.com/1703_SQL_Injection_in_Classic_ASP_and_Possible_Solutions.all